# Get html tags and loop over them using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, terminal, grep

I have this input file

```
<article class="article column large-12 small-12 article--nyheter">
    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14341175/">
        <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:42.075%;">

            <img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt="" />


        </figure>
        <div class="article__content">
            <h2 class="article__title t54 tm24">Mann savnet etter &Atilde;&yen; ha blitt angrepet av to haier</h2>
        </div>
    </a>

</article>
<article class="article column large-6 small-6 article--nyheter">
    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14315514/">
        <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:42.075%;">

            <img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt="" />
                

        </figure>
        <div class="article__content">
            <h2 class="article__title t34 tm24">Flere blir 100 &Atilde;&yen;r &acirc;&#128;&#147; Tordis (102) tror hun
                vet noe av oppskriften</h2>
        </div>
    </a>

</article>
<article class="article column large-6 small-6 article--nyheter">
    <a class="article__link" href="/nyheter/14336393/">
        <figure class="image image__responsive" style="padding-bottom:42.075%;">

            <img class="image__img lazyload" itemprop="image" title="" alt="" />


        </figure>
        <div class="article__content">
            <h2 class="article__title t34 tm24">To menn i 30-&Atilde;&yen;rene tiltalt for grov voldtekt av mann tidlig
                i 20-&Atilde;&yen;rene</h2>
        </div>
    </a>

</article>
```

These are three article tags. I want to make three files from these three article tags having info from them. Example of the output would be

news1.txt

```
http://example.no/news/123456789/af31/4928  // link (a tag)
Franzens djevelsk gode forstadsfabel // name (h2 tag)
http://imgs.example.no/pics/0291817572384234.jpg // image (img tag)
2021-10-27 10:45 // date (when the file was created)
```

Can this be done in bash using sed, awk?

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Can you also give some help using this xml parser?

Comment: none of the content of the `news1.txt` file exists in the provided sample inputs; please update the question with sample inputs and expected outputs that ***match***

Comment: Please post valid XML.